# Remove extra social network options / Cordova Plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have added https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin and it's working fine. But my question is how to remove unwanted social sharing options from the sharing list for **android device.**

I want only twitter,facebook,google+, gmail,sms and whatsapp options in the list.

Comment: Read the documentation. Or Ask the author of the plugin.

Comment: If I asked here maybe it's because I didn't find the answer in the documentation.

Comment: This means, you can't do it, or the author has not documented it. Chances are that at least 10 other people need this and have not asked. ***Ask.**